# How to login User on other account while he's already logged in on his?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

User is logged in on account "A" via Identity

```
signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(UserName, Password, false, lockoutOnFailure: true);
```

That's how I'm performing Logout

```
await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
```

and it works fine, but when I want to "throw" current user on other account - account "B"

```
await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);
```

then it does not work, user is still on his "previous" "A" account

Even if I perform

```
await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();

await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);
```

then my User is still on his "previous" "A" account.

Over all it is weird, because it worked for last X months and I have no idea what's wrong because there's no error.

**Basically using**

```
await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
```

**alone works correctly, but using it with SignIn does not.**

Even performing

```
foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.Keys)
{
    Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);
}
```

before SignIn does not help

## Edit

Here's how I do register and config an Identity:

```
services.AddEditedDefaultIdentity<User>
(
    o =>
    {
        o.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        o.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        o.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    }
)
.AddSignInManager()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>();

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Login";
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyApp";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(600);
    options.LoginPath = "/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Logout";

    options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

---

```
public static IdentityBuilder AddEditedDefaultIdentity<TUser>(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IdentityOptions> configureOptions) where TUser : class
{
    services.AddAuthentication(o =>
    {
        o.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        o.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
    .AddIdentityCookies(o => { });

    return services.AddIdentityCore<TUser>(o =>
    {
        o.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128;
        configureOptions?.Invoke(o);
    })
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
}
```

Comment: Please check the difference between your code and my answer. How to reproduce your issue with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo for me:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SignInAnother()
{
    //A sign in with username and password
    var AsignInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync("tony@outlook.com","1qaz@WSX", false, true);
    //A sign out
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    //query identity user by username
    var username = "test@outlook.com";
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
    //sign in user
    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Create two different methods: 1st one is peforming ``PasswordSignIn``, second one is ``SignInAnother``, then use first to log onto account, verify whether you're logged in on your page, then click on e.g url that enters ``SignInAnother`` that just signs out and sign ins on other user (so just loggs in other account)

Comment: I edited my post, I think it may be very helpful (Identity settings)

Comment: @Joelty Can you reproduce your issue with simple demo? I fail to reproduce even I spilt them into two methods.

Comment: Hey, I found solution, Check post above if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Problem occured because Identity was creating **TWO** cookies with ID of session?user? not sure

but they had different paths for some reason

So,

- I'm logging in on Account A
- It's creating cookie for Account A
- I'm "throwing myself" / "logging in" on Account B
- It's creating cookie for Account B
- I'm entering [Authorize] endpoint
- and it reads first? cookie for Account A
- Then I'm removing Account's A cookie
- Refreshing Page
- and now I'm on account B.

[image]

So I gotta try to fix path of those created cookies.

## edit

Fix:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    (...)
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
});
```